# c# regex: get all uri's, but not from a specific domain

Tags: c#, regex

i have a c# regex, which gives me all uri's in a document.
it's this:

```
<a[^>]*\shref=[\""\'][^>]*"
```

this one works, but i want to exclude al uri's (matches) which have the word 'doubleclick.net' in it, because those uri's i want to leave untouched, and the others i want to add some code to.

i've tried this:
    ((?!doubleclick.net).) somewhere in between
found here
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/arjen/archive/2008/12/03/regex-exclude-lines-containing-a-specific-word.aspx
but it doesn't work for me....

Michel

Comment: Didn't get an answer, not an issue anymore. Can't delete the question though...

Comment: what was your result on this? Would love to see and answer

Answer (score 2):

[Please don't use regexes to parse HTML!](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

Grab a copy of the [HTML agility pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) and your life will be much simpler, and your application much less brittle.

Comment: hmm, in my case, which has kind of fixed or known html, the regex works. So i appreciate your concern, but it doesn't solve my problem